# Ubuntu Live CD/Live USB problem

Tags: boot, live-usb, live-cd

I have a problem when trying to boot from a live CD, and the same problem also happens with a Live USB.

The problem that I have is that when I boot, the sidebar the the topbar load and look ok, they function normally, but the major issue is that the Windows, Background, and Drop-Down menus are all corrupted, the Background just looks like what happens if you open a .exe as a paint image, and the other things look like a corrupted window with a thick Ubuntu-themed bar bordering it, I was wondering if there is a problem with my system.

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, could a another distro be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to see that problem when the new gnome3 first came out, it had corrupted "snowy" "old-tv-set-to-no-channel" type stuff here & there, and half the letters of various text was missing (just not there, like invisible letters).

I think it was caused somehow by gnome + possibly unsupported graphics drivers, never fixed it but eventually gnome upgrades fixed it. In the meantime you could try a different desktop environment and see if it still happens, like xfce, or lxde, or kde, or cinnamon, or mate, or just a different window manager like fluxbox...

Ubuntu has different live iso's for different desktop envirnoments, like Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu...

If others show the same corruption then maybe you need a specific or updated graphics driver which could be hard to do or impossible when running a live iso (can't reboot and save changes, though persistence might work). You could try a different distro, one based off of Ubuntu like Linux Mint should be very very similar to Ubuntu, or one not even based on Debian (like fedora, suse, slackware, could be very different.

Comment: Turns out that the latest Ubuntu version (14.10) works fine, mabye support for the graphics card I have was prob implemented, still, thx for the answer!

Comment: That was probably what happened, bug fixed or better/more support upstream. That's a pretty general answer for any bug, "try the latest version" (or "fix it yourself" ;-)